# Sorting two int[] by same criteria

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have two int[], Start and End. They refer to a series of lines: Start[0] is the start position of line 0 and End[0] is to the end position of line 0. I want to sort Start in ascending order and then sort End in the same way, so the arrays stay aligned.

In MatLab, you can do this:

[idx, StartSorted] = sort(Start); 
EndSorted = End(idx);

What is the best way to do the same operation in Java? Write a tuple class, or is there a better way?

In general, what is the best way to manipulate paired data like this?

Thak you.

---

Thanks guys, that's great.

Comment: It might be me, but a sorted map sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be, as you stated, to create a `Tuple` class of some sort that maintains both values. You should also implement `equals` and make your class implement [`Comparable<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and implement `compareTo`. Once you have done that, you can sort a collection of `Tuple` instances (using [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-)) and they will be sorted according to the ordering specified by your `compareTo` method. In this particular instance, your comparison will simply be based on the value of `start` in `Tuple`.

If you don't care so much about defining implicit ordering for your class by implementing `Comparable<T>`, you can specify an ad-hoc comparator using [`Comparator#comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and use it with an array of your objects:

```
//tuples is an array
//Tuple::getStart is a method reference to the getStart method
//in tuple. So you get an ad-hoc comparator that uses this
//function as the basis for ordering
Arrays.sort(tuples, Comparator.comparingInt(Tuple::getStart)
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use two arrays of `int`. Use a **single** array of `Line`, where `Line` would be a class having a `start` property and an `end` property.

Then, to sort lines by their start (in Java 8):

```
Arrays.sort(lines, Comparator.comparingInt(Line::getStart));
```